# RAII approach for a container of containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Assuming that my `T` is a vector `typedef std::vector<ofSomething> T;` ( it's usually a vector around 4-5 MB, it's expensive to recreate and store as it is in a data structure )

so, considering :

- pointers
- references
- smart pointers

I have to create a container of vectors, or I have to put all this vectors together somehow, I'm wondering what is the best approach according to the RAII philosophy .

`std::container<T*>`

or

`std::container<T&>`

or

`std::container<unique_ptr<T>>`

with pointers I need to call the destructor explicitly, and this doesn't really look and sound like RAII at all.

with references it's basically the same as with pointers.

with smart pointers I get what I want if I delete or just "drop" the object representing the smart pointer.

Is a collection of smart pointers a really good idea for a container of containers ? I don't know, they are here to express ownership not for automatic memory management, it sounds like I'm doing something wrong with the wrong philosophy, at the same time I have multiple big containers to handle until they "expire" or they are not needed anymore.

What you suggest ?

Comment: `std::container<T>`. The fact that the `T` can contain several megabytes is irrelevant if it's never copied (read about move semantics)

Comment: `std::container<T&>` is impossible as is.

Comment: I'm posting here since this is too chatty to be an answer: RAII works in every case if **you do it properly**. Pointers? Remember to allocate and deallocate properly in constructors/destructors. Smart pointers? They take care of the out-of-scope memory cleanup. You can't have a std::vector of references :)

Comment: my example was intended to be as generic as possible, don't focus on the impossibility of `T&` inside standard containers .

Comment: @milleniumbug For some reason when I first answered, I had it in my head that the containers involved were `std::array`. Perhaps because the premise of the question makes sense then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a vector of vectors, and you want RAII, then the answer is so simple:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> v;
```

… no references or pointers in sight.

If you're concerned about the inner containers being moved around as the outer vector grows, flatten it:

```
std::vector<T>
```

and wrap the indexing, so that `i = x*W+y`.

Comment: with this, try to drop the vector at the `x` index and see how much re-location you need to do in memory. This is good, but this also shows that a vector is 1 chunk of memory and it's not that flexible when you need multiple entities that are likely to experience different lifetimes .

Comment: @user2485710: Then reserve what you need ahead of time. Implement move semantics. Flatten the structure. There is _no_ need to overcomplicate this.

Comment: @user2485710 You haven't stated your requirements. It looks you're employing the [for-if antipattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx).

Comment: @milleniumbug I'm lazy, the move semantics will do that for me, I was just trying to optimize things, it's also a problem about code readability, if you are going to introduce a new pattern, you are going to make the code a bit less clear each time you do that. Move semantics it's standard, and it comes from the language itself.

Comment: @user2485710 depending on the implementation pushing content to the vector doesn't necessarily copy-construct all containing objects even when memory reallocation is required. You can also use std::deque or std::list instead to ensure this.

Comment: Move semantics are standard but you still need your types to be move-aware. If your `T` is complex then that's on you; the language can't always automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, with a raw pointer you'll need to do your own memory management - scratch that. You can't store a reference in a standard container because allocators are not defined for reference types, and you'll still need to allocate your objects on the heap somehow - scratch that. The `std::unique_ptr` will perform memory management for you and actually compile - this wins... from your choices.

But what about `std::container<T>`? This will also work fine and not have any issues with manual memory management. It will also benefit from move semantics, so you don't need to worry about the vectors being copied. You also avoid an extra level of indirection.

Obviously using a `std::unique_ptr` restricts what you can do with your container. If you need to be able to copy it and/or its items, you'll want `std::shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: regarding references I was just assuming "any kind of container", my example was really generic. If I'm not mistaking I have heard some references here and there that smart pointers are not an optimal choice for automatic memory management, I also remember this section of a talk of Sean Parent on Channel 9 about how good smart pointers are and they are probably not that good for memory. Anyway I can see your point which is in fact my original point.

Comment: @user2485710 I've not seen this talk, but that doesn't sound quite right. Smart pointers are not that good for memory?

Comment: In that talk Sean Parent end up defining smart pointers "as good as global variables" which doesn't sound terribly cool to me, especially for memory management, but there wasn't too much technicality involved in his talk, probably some subtle references to the philosophy behind smart pointers and their own policies, but what I got from that talk is that smart pointers are not that good for this but I don't exactly got his point and why.

Comment: `Sean Parent end up defining smart pointers "as good as global variables"` He doesn't know what he's talking about. The _whole point_ of smart pointers is to enable RAII.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, he got on the stage of one of the most important C++ conferences in the world and one of the most popular event related to C++. That's why I have some doubts about this. The problem is that the talk was more about code styles then smart pointers, so I basically have no idea what he was aiming at in the technical sense.

Comment: @user2485710: If you're going to take nonsense at face value just as an appeal to authority, then you've already lost.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not saying that, after hearing that I was between "wait what?" and "ok, but why he is saying that ?" . It's one of those things that you hear and that can be both true and false until you can get someone to give you a good explanation for that. Certainly he wasn't clear about this.

Comment: @user2485710 Sean Parent was specifically talking about `shared_ptr` being "as good as a global variable" because, much like a global variable, you can't be certain where the pointee is being used elsewhere in the program.

Comment: There you go then; you misinterpreted it.

Comment: @user2485710 I just watched his talk, and yes, he's actually talking more generally about mutable reference semantics (without explicitly saying it). As far as RAII is concerned, the smart pointers are great. But yes, the better choice of smart pointer here would be `unique_ptr` because it doesn't have the problem of mutable references.